# Refresh page after jQuery Mobile transitions in PhoneGap apps

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I´m new to PhoneGap Cordova. I have a login script where once logged in successfully it  redirects to another page, but while redirecting the page, the page is getting flicker or white and then it loads the page. For redirecting the page I have used normal `window.location="home.html"`.

If I use:

```
$.mobile.changePage("home,html",{transition:"slide"});
```

it will load the page but i want to refresh the `home.html` page only.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the jQuery Mobile multi page template? http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.1.1/docs/pages/multipage-template.html

In mobile applications is very common to use a single page application model (single HTML file) that has several "pages" or "views" in it, so you just switch between them without need to load any other HTML.

Comment: hi @orlando rinco thanks for your reply , ya know about that but in my app three diffrent users are there ex : enduser,admin,superadmin, for each  of them i have created separate pages like user.html,admin.html and superadmin.html ,in index.html i have created log in view, as soon as userlogs in successfully page need to redirect to respective users page . please help me thanks